# A question on the punctured plane as a cartesian product

Tags: general-topology

I am studying about the construction of homeomorphisms of topological spaces. I am able to digest the fact that the cylinder defined by
\begin{align*}
C = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2 = 1\}
\end{align*}
can be expressed as a cartesian product $S \times \mathbb{R}$ (clearly this must be composed of three coordinates, i.e., a 3-tuple) where $S$ is the unit circle defined by $S = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ but why is it that the punctured plane
defined by $\Pi^* = \mathbb{R}^2 \; \backslash \; \{(0,0)\}$ can also be expressed as $S \times (0, +\infty)$? While I get it that somehow, the nonzero interval represents the radius of the circle in the punctured plane, but how can a 3-tuple be representative of an ordered pair? I can imagine the cartesian product as a set of points with 3-perpendicular axes, hence the cylinder having the unit circle as the base and the $z$-axis representative of real line as its infinite height.

Comment: I see that you have a general-topology tag, but you do not say what you mean mean by the phrase "...can be expressed as...". Is your intent that this phrase has a topological meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Well, all we care is that $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1\times (0,\infty)$, not that they are set-theoretically equal. To help your imagination, first think of $\mathbb{S}^1\times (0,\infty)$ as a cylinder, than shrink the circle on $0$-end so that it becomes a (empty) point. Now whole $\mathbb{S}^1\times (0,\infty)$ looks like a cone. Then we just need to press this cone into $\mathbb{R}^2$, except $0$ where it corresponds our empty point(which was $0$-end circle). Clearly this procedure is homeomorphism, so we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f:\Pi^* \to S \times (0,\infty )$ by $$f(x,y)=((\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}),\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$$